# There was a problem using Spring MVC. There is also getter, but I wonder if the binding is wrong

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using `Spring MVC` and `thymeleaf` to do the Toy Project. Then I encountered an error that I didn't know where I got it wrong.

```
Invalid property 'monday' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'monday' is not readable or has an invalid getter method
```

I tried googling, and there were many people who encountered the same error as me, but I don't think my code has anything to do with what I wrote as a solution. Because what's written in the solution is already in my code.

Please tell me what I'm making a mistake in any part would be appreciated.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ParticipateRoom {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "participant_room_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "study_id")
    private StudyRoom room;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    private Member member;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name ="user_id")
    private User user;

    private String warning;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MemberStatus status;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ParticipateStatus participateStatus;

    private LocalDateTime updateDate;

    @Setter
    private String monday;
    @Setter
    private String tuesday;
    @Setter
    private String wednesday;
    @Setter
    private String thursday;
    @Setter
    private String friday;
    @Setter
    private String saturday;
    @Setter
    private String sunday;


    public ParticipateRoom(StudyRoom room, Member member, User user, String warning,
                           MemberStatus status, ParticipateStatus participateStatus,
                           LocalDateTime updateDate, String monday, String tuesday, String wednesday,
                           String thursday, String friday, String saturday, String sunday) {
        this.room = room;
        this.member = member;
        this.user = user;
        this.warning = warning;
        this.status = status;
        this.participateStatus = participateStatus;
        this.updateDate = updateDate;

        this.monday = monday;
        this.tuesday = tuesday;
        this.wednesday = wednesday;
        this.thursday = thursday;
        this.friday = friday;
        this.saturday = saturday;
        this.sunday = sunday;
    }

    public void allDayReset() {
        this.monday = null;
        this.tuesday = null;
        this.wednesday = null;
        this.thursday = null;
        this.friday = null;
        this.saturday = null;
        this.sunday = null;
    }

    public void setUpdateDate(LocalDateTime now) {
        this.updateDate = now;
    }
}
```

```
    @GetMapping("/submit_study/{roomId}")
    public String submitStudy(@PathVariable("roomId") String roomId, Model model) {
        SubmitStudyDto dto = new SubmitStudyDto();

        StudyRoom findStudy = studyRoomRepository.findByRoomId(roomId);

        List<ParticipateRoom> findParticipate = participateRoomService.findByRoomId(roomId);

        model.addAttribute("study", findStudy);
        model.addAttribute("checkList", findParticipate);
        model.addAttribute("submit", dto);

        return "room/submit_study";
    }
```

```
    @Override
    public List<ParticipateRoom> findByRoomId(String roomId) {
        return queryFactory
                .selectFrom(participateRoom)
                .leftJoin(participateRoom.room, studyRoom).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(participateRoom.member, member).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(participateRoom.user, user).fetchJoin()
                .where(
                        studyRoom.roomId.eq(roomId)
                )
                .fetch();
    }
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form th:action="@{/submit_study/{roomId}(roomId = ${study.roomId})}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:object="${submit}">
        <input type="file" name="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="제출하기">

        <div th:if="${#fields.hasGlobalErrors()}" class="global_error">
            <p class="field-error" th:each="err : ${#fields.globalErrors()}" th:text="${err}"></p>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div th:each="checkList : ${checkList}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="monday" disabled th:field="${checkList.monday}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" disabled th:field="${checkList.tuesday}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="wednesday" disabled th:field="${checkList.wednesday}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="thursday" disabled th:field="${checkList.thursday}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="friday" disabled th:field="${checkList.friday}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="saturday" disabled th:field="${checkList.saturday}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sunday" disabled th:field="${checkList.sunday}">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `th:each="checkList : ${checkList}">` you are using the same argument for the list and the individual element. `${checkList}` is the reference to the list and `checkList` the individual element. As they are both the same the next one `${checkList.monday}` references the list and not the individual element.

Comment: @M.Deinum I think the problem you mentioned is correct. So I changed the `checkList` to `participate`. Then, the above problem did not occur. But another problem arose. I want to hear your opinion on this matter. `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'participate' available as request attribute`

Comment: Yuor list is added to the model as `checkList` if you change the HTML you also need to change the attributename in the model.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried to solve it, but it didn't work, so I solved the problem in a different way. Thank you for leaving comments.

Comment: Those kind of comments are generally quite scary and instead of understanding and actually solving the problem, mean hacking around as long as it works. Working around the frameworks in use... generally a bad idea.

Comment: @M.Deinum 
Rather, the `th:field` I usually use was to be used with `th:object`. However, this time, the checkbox is not used as a checkbox, but simply for display purposes, so this problem occurred after using a different syntax than usual. So, instead of using `th:field`, using `th:classappend` to add a class if it contains a value and check only the class added by `javascript` means that the problem was solved.